# Does the C++ namespace clause function like the using clause in that it resolves ambigious scope?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Let's say I have a type named ModuleObject which is declared in another file and that thistype lives in the Module namespace.  Then let's say I have **another file** that uses the namespace clause to introduce additional names into the namespace, like so:

```
namespace Module { 
  ....
```

When I refer to the ModuleObject type inside this second file, which is correct?

```
namespace Module { 
  Module::ModuleObject mo;
```

Or, since I declared "namespace Module", will the scope automatically be determined by the compiler?

```
ModuleObject mo;
```

I am not sure if the namespace clause functions like the using namespace clause, in that it resolves scope to the namespace declared.

Comment: If you have previously declared `ModuleObject` in the namespace `Module` in the same translation unit then it will refer to `Module::ModuleObject`. When the compiler sees `ModuleObject` it performs unqualified name lookup. It will look in the current namespace (`Module`) and find `ModuleObject`, so it stops the recursive namespace search and uses `Module::ModuleObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope will be determined by the compiler - as long as you include the original file in the second one, eg.

```
// ModuleObject.h

namespace Module
{ 
    class ModuleObject
    {
    };
}

// SecondFile.h

#include "ModuleObject.h"

namespace Module
{
    ModuleObject obj;
}
```

By the way, is it really so hard just to try before asking on SO?